# what is key in CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders and CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology

Tags: ios, swift, core-telephony

I'm playing around with CoreTelephony framework to get some information about cellular data provider out of it. I execute below code:

```swift
let obj = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
if let array = obj.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders {
    for (key, value) in array {
        print("{")
        print("\(key)=<\(value.carrierName)>")
        print("\(key)=<\(value.mobileCountryCode)>")
        print("\(key)=<\(value.mobileNetworkCode)>")
        print("}")
    }
}

if let array = obj.serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology {
    for (key, value) in array1 {
        print("{")
        print("\(key)=<\(value)>")
        print("}")
    }
}
```

I get this out put:

```
{
    0000000100000001=<Optional("Carrier")>
    0000000100000001=<Optional("432")>
    0000000100000001=<Optional("11")>
}
{
    0000000100000001=<CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE>
}
```

**Question**
I'm wondering what is "0000000100000001" and what information we can get from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/cttelephonynetworkinfo/3024510-servicecurrentradioaccesstechnol) are pretty clear now:

> Although the actual value of a key isn’t important, you can also use it to get the carrier information associated with the service. To do so, pass the key to the serviceSubscriberCellularProviders dictionary.

So you can pass the "0000000100000001" as key to `serviceSubscriberCellularProviders`.

I think the API was changed to accommodate for [iPhones with multiple SIMs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209044).